# Linux Tomcat Errors

Tags: linux, tomcat, console, localhost, catalina.out

I'm having trouble launching tomcat on my linux server. I run startup.sh, and get the Tomcat Started logging, but then can't access anything on localhost:8080.

```
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /home/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.11
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /home/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.11
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /home/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /home/tomcat/jdk1.8.0_121
Using CLASSPATH:       /home/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/bin/bootstrap.jar:/home                                                                                        /tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
```

Checking the logs/catalina.out file, there are the following lines in there, but I haven't been able to find any information about these errors.

```
/home/tomcat/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java: 1: /home/tomcat/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java: ^?ELF^A^A^A^B^C^A: not found
/home/tomcat/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java: 2: /home/tomcat/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Any ideas?

Comment: can you do `file /home/tomcat/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java`. Looks like your Java binaries are either not suitable for your platform, or corrupt.

Comment: @geert3 , I concur. On my Intel system, the header of ELF files is not (once ASCII-ed) `^?ELF^A^A^A^B^C` - haven't checked the ELF format for its significance, but I suspect they're for a different platform. The question should perhaps be updated with the platform details.

Comment: Can you try and check the following things and report back. - Did you check the java binaries which you downloaded are Linux ones ? Please also ensure the correct architecture. - Did some program overwrite those binaries. Check the modification time. - Is the binary a partial download ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: As suggested by others, it could be due to the binaries from a different platform or perhaps something to do with shell script parsing. To isolate. can you get back whether you are able to execute the following command : `$ /home/tomcat/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java -version` ?

Answer (score 8):

**Update**

I've decoded the ELF header from your error message: `^?ELF^A^A^A^B^C^A`

It is a bunch of [caret encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation) control characters,
which can be decoded as follows:

First 4 bytes are a *magic number*, identifying the file as an [ELF](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) executable.

```
0x7f (^?) - ELFMAG0 
0x45 (E)  - ELFMAG1
0x4c (L)  - ELFMAG2
0x46 (F)  - ELFMAG3
```

Next 3 bytes specify the architecture, the endianness and the ELF format version:

```
0x01 (^A) - ELFCLASS32  (i.e. this is a 32 bit binary)
0x01 (^A) - ELFDATA2LSB (Little Endian)
0x01 (^A) - EI_VERSION  (Version of ELF format EV_CURRENT/1)
```

So basically it is a **32-bit** Java binary.

Then, I've downloaded the 32-bit version of JRE (jre1.8.0_121), and tried to run *java* with *dash*, to confirm my shell issue theory (below), and it does indeed produce exactly the same error message you have:

```
%dash ./java|&less
./java: 1: ./java: ^?ELF^A^A^A^B^C^A: not found
./java: 2: ./java: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

> So, most probably, you are using a 32-bit version of Java (as bundled with your Tomcat), on a machine, which is not capable (or configured) to run 32-bit executables. And a shell issue (as described below), then masks the underlying problem, which is why you get this weird looking error message.

It is hard to say more without having a bit more details on your system,
so output of `uname -a` and `cat /etc/lsb-release` would be nice to have.

---

...

My bet is that this might be a shell issue, i.e. your `/bin/sh` points to something like *dash*, which might cause some compatibility issues with *catalina.sh* script, and make it interpret `bin/java` as a script, instead of running it as an executable, under certain circumstances.

In particular older versions of *dash* are known to executes binary data as a shell script in case of ENOEXEC (i.e. corrupted and/or invalid architecture binary) (see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=816313;msg=5).

And your error message

```
/home/tomcat/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java: 2: /home/tomcat/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

looks very much like it.

You can check what your `/bin/sh` points to, like that:

```
>ls -l /bin/sh
/bin/sh -> bash
```

If it is not *bash*, then modify the *shebang* line in your */home/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.5.11/bin/catalina.sh* as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and see if it helps, or at least produces a more readable error message.

In case *bash* fails with `cannot execute binary file`, check if your `java` binary is not corrupted and can be executed on your system, by running it by hand:

```
/home/tomcat/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java
```